# chrome.app.window.onMaximized event fired too early?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-app

So, I've been working on a Chrome app where I am using  tags, and need to resize them after the app size has changed.  I have some code below which roughly describes my problem.  I am using jQuery, and in the $.ready() function, I add listeners to the fullscreen and maximize events, where I call a function resizeStage.  My

```
function App() {
    this.init = init;
    this.resizeStage = resizeStage;

    function resizeStage() {
          console.log(chrome.app.window.current().isMaximized());
          var docWidth = $(document).width();
          var docHeight = $(document).height();
          console.log('resizeStage', docWidth, docHeight);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var app = new App();
  app.init();

  /*
  chrome.app.window.current().onFullscreened.addListener(function () {
      console.log('onFullscreened');
      app.resizeStage();
  });
  */

  chrome.app.window.current().onMaximized.addListener(function () {
      console.log('onMaximized');
      app.resizeStage();
  });
});
```

And the output is something like this

```
true app.js:43
resizeStage 1042 780 app.js:48
```

which is too small (I have a 30" CinemaDisplay).  If I put a breakpoint on the first line in resizeStage, and run the following commands in the console, I see

```
$(document).height();
1400
$(document).width();
2568
```

so, it would seem to me that the maximize event is getting fired before the window reaches it's full size.  Is this the intended behavior, and is so, what is the best way to wait until the window has been full resized to query for the current app window size?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug to me, file it as one at http://crbug.com/new and edit this stack overlow question with the bug ID number so others can star it to track updates.